# Select a item from an Autocomplete Material UI Listbox in Cypress

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete, cypress, listboxitem

This is the element.

```js
<input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Category" type="text" 
  class="MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiInputBase-input 
    MuiInputBase-inputAdornedEnd MuiAutocomplete-input 
    MuiAutocomplete-inputFocused MuiAutocomplete-input 
    MuiAutocomplete-inputFocused css-16sx77j" 
  aria-autocomplete="list" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" 
  value="" id="mui-621338585" 
  aria-controls="mui-621338585-listbox" 
  aria-activedescendant="mui-621338585-option-3">
```

This is a listbox with the name Category that contains various options when I click the dropdown arrow. The number after "mui-" is dynamic.

This is what I tried:

```js
cy.get('[id^=”mui-"]').eq(2);
```

Also tried:

```js
cy.get('[id^=”mui-"]')
  .find('[aria-activedescendant*="-option-"]')
  .eq(2);
```

And tried:

```js
cy.get('[aria-activedescendant*="-option-2"]');
```

Could someone point me in the right direction to select an option from the listbox?

Answer (score 3):

Don't over-think the problem, just use text in the component.

Libraries like React Material-UI generate quite complicated HTML to handle styling and animation and it's difficult to pick the right parts from that generated HTML.

Given source code like this (taken from MUI demo page)

```html
<Autocomplete
  disablePortal
  id="combo-box-demo"
  options={top100Films}
  sx={{ width: 300 }}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
/>
```

You get a generated structure like this (leaving out classes used for styling)

```html
<div class="MuiAutocomplete-root" data-cy="movie-autocomplete">
  <div>
    <label for="combo-box-demo" id="combo-box-demo-label">Movie</label>
    <div>
      <input id="combo-box-demo" type="text" role="combobox" value="">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `MUIAutocomplete-root` is outer element - you can test it using the text in the elements.

```js
cy.contains('.MuiAutocomplete-root', 'Movie')  // identify Autocomplete component
  .click()                                     // open it

cy.contains('The Godfather').click()           // choose an option

cy.contains('.MuiAutocomplete-root', 'Movie')  
  .find('input')                               
  .should('have.value', 'The Godfather')       // verify the value in the input
```

---

#### With data-cy attribute

If you add a `data-cy` attribute to the component,

```html
<Autocomplete
  data-cy='movie-autocomplete'
  disablePortal
  id="combo-box-demo"
  options={top100Films}
  sx={{ width: 300 }}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
/>
```

The test becomes simpler

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="movie-autocomplete"]').click()

cy.contains('The Godfather').click()

cy.get('[data-cy="movie-autocomplete"]')
  .find('input')
  .should('have.value', 'The Godfather')
```

Comment: thankyou Fody! It really did work, somehow I never thought or always had it in mind that it might recognize using the text in the elements or the label!!